# WPF databinding a gridview issue

Tags: wpf

I am working on a dataGrid that is populated from an Entity model. I have the following for the specific column as an attempt to use a combobox during editing and the source for the editing is a CollectionsViewSource.

```
      <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource vsLogins}" Grid.Column="1" 
            Margin="16,248,154,31">
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" 
                  Height="213" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource vsLogins}}" 
                  Name="LoginsDataGrid"
                  RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="380"
                  Background="{StaticResource lgb}" BorderThickness="2" 
                  BorderBrush="#FFFC0303">
          <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="LoginNameColumn" Binding="{Binding 
                                  Path=LoginName}" Header="Login Name"
                                  Width="200" MinWidth="200" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="PsWrdColumn"
                                Binding="{Binding Path=PsWrd}" 
                                Header="Password" Width="130" MinWidth="130" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="AccessLevelIdColumn" Header="Id"
                                    Width="40" MinWidth="40">
              <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=AccessLevelId}" />
                </DataTemplate>
              </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                  <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource 
                             vsAccessLevels}}" DisplayMemberPath="Description" 
                         SelectedValuePath="AccessLevelId" IsEditable="False"/>
                </DataTemplate>
              </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
          </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

It is throwing some errors. What am I doing wrong? I also tried putting a grid around the combobox and setting it's dataContent to the CVS - no dice either. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Any reasons for not using `DataGridComboboxColumn' and what error you are getting?

Comment: Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception. My table has a field that is related to another table I was wanting the right was to access it inside the DG? That is what I am up to basically.

Comment: So things are getting better. I can get the combobox to show up when in editing mode and the items are from the related table, however when I select one I get a 0 instead of the underlying value from the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="AccessIdColumn" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource vsAccessLevels}}" 
                        DisplayMemberPath="Description" 
                        SelectedValuePath="AccessLevelId"
                        SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=AccessLevelId}"/>
```